# Не работает git pull

Tags: git, gitlab, git-pull

Создан git clone репозитория.
В нем удаляем несколько файлов
делаем git pull этого же репозитория
пишет все уже обновлено, и удаленные файлы не добавляются, никаких изменений или ошибок не происходит. В том числе и измененный репозиторий все равно пишет что обновлен и всё... 
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: после удаления файлов, коммит делали?

Answer (score 1):

Откатитесь до состояния прошлого коммита `git reset --hard HEAD`

Либо можно восстановить отдельный файл. Для этого 
1. Ищем последний коммит где файл существовал `git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- имя_файла`
2. Восстанавливаем нужный файл `git checkout найденный_коммит^ -- имя_файла`

Comment: а зачем искать и указывать «последний коммит»? `$ git checkout имя-файла` — вполне справляется с извлечением файла из хранилища.

Comment: Как вариант, однако если по одному файлу, то опять же неудобно, проще всего откатить до последнего коммита, конечно если нет критичных изменений

Comment: можно и не по одному, а сразу несколько файлов распаковать: `$ git checkout -- файл1 файл2 ...`

Comment: тоже неплохой вариант в принципе)

Comment: сделал git reset --hard HEAD. После этого вернулись все удаленные файлы, но более старой версии. не пойму откуда, есть две ветки, в обеих (сутя по просмотрщику на гитлабе) новые версии). Как теперь взять свежую версию? О_о

Comment: Переключиться на нужную ветку и обновить из нее. Вообще git rev-list надо было сразу посмотреть и вместо HEAD написать заголовок коммита, который нужен

Comment: да, уже попробовал... разницы нет. САМОЕ интересное, что те же последовательности и команды на локальном компьютере работают отлично. в чем тогда дело может быть?

Comment: Может у вас локальный репозиторий не синхронизирован с удаленным?

Comment: как можно это проверить? remote делал